# Regex.Replace("...abc-10-11-09?", ..., ...)

Tags: c#

I have a String like

```
str1 = "...abc-10-11-09?"
```

and I need to replace *the last* `"-09"`.
So that result will be like

```
"...abc-10-11-2?"
```

I have try

```
Regex.Replace(str1, @"([0-9]+)\?", "$1-2?"),
```

but I became `"...abc-10-11-09-2?"`

Could someone help me please.
Thank you.

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(str1, @"[0-9]+\?$", "2?");`

Comment: `$1` is a reference to the match - so you replace 09 with 09-2 - use `Regex.Replace(str1, @"([0-9]+)\?", "2"), `

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the $1 if you only want to replace the last number.

```
Regex.Replace(str1, @"([0-9]+)\?", "2?")
```

would work

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str1, @"-[0-9]+\?$", "-2?");
```

please, notice that we:

1. Just replace (no `$1`)
2. Achor `$` (we want to replace the *last* ocurrence only)

Comment: Thank you so mach for fast answer! This do what I wont: Regex.Replace(str1, @"([0-9]+)\?", "2?")

Comment: @que: I've put `-[0-9]+\?$` (starts with `-`) since the question says "replace the last `"-09"`" (starts with `-`). If you accept *any delimiter*, e.g. `...abc*10*11*09?` (please, notice `*`) should be `...abc*10*11*2?` then your regex is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(str1, @"-[0-9]+\?$", "-2?");
```

if you also want to properly handle the `-`.